# Error running ccny_rgbd

Tags: ros, openni, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey I'm trying to run the ccny_rgbd package. I have everything built properly but when I run

```
ccny_openni_launch openni.launch publish_cloud:=true
```

I get a lot of errors.

```
nft@nft-desktop:~/ros_workspace/ccny_rgbd_tools$ roslaunch
ccny_openni_launch openni.launch publish_cloud:=true
... logging to
/home/nft/.ros/log/5efebfd8-1e6b-11e3-981d-74f06d80936b/roslaunch-nft-desktop-25268.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server [hidden]

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
* /openni_driver/depth_camera_info_url
* /openni_driver/depth_frame_id
* /openni_driver/depth_mode
* /openni_driver/device_id
* /openni_driver/image_mode
* /openni_driver/rgb_camera_info_url
* /openni_driver/rgb_frame_id
* /rgbd_image_proc/calib_path
* /rgbd_image_proc/publish_cloud
* /rgbd_image_proc/scale
* /rgbd_image_proc/unwarp
* /rgbd_image_proc/verbose
* /rosdistro
* /rosversion

NODES
 /
   camera_rgb_frame_tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)
   camera_rgb_optical_frame_tf (tf/static_transform_publisher)
   debayer (nodelet/nodelet)
   openni_driver (nodelet/nodelet)
   rgbd_image_proc (nodelet/nodelet)
   rgbd_manager (nodelet/nodelet)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [25284]
ROS_MASTER_URI=[hidden]

setting /run_id to 5efebfd8-1e6b-11e3-981d-74f06d80936b
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [25297]
started core service [/rosout]
process[rgbd_manager-2]: started with pid [25309]
process[openni_driver-3]: started with pid [25320]
[ INFO] [1379293230.457714541]: Initializing nodelet with 2 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1379293230.569478335]: Loading nodelet /openni_driver of type
openni_camera/driver to manager rgbd_manager with the following
remappings:
[ INFO] [1379293230.570003891]: /depth -> /camera/depth
[ INFO] [1379293230.570188411]: /ir -> /camera/ir
[ INFO] [1379293230.570338431]: /rgb -> /camera/rgb
process[debayer-4]: started with pid [25361]
process[rgbd_image_proc-5]: started with pid [25379]
process[camera_rgb_frame_tf-6]: started with pid [25401]
process[camera_rgb_optical_frame_tf-7]: started with pid [25417]
[FATAL] [1379293235.769048546]: Service call failed!
[rgbd_manager-2] process has died [pid 25309, exit code -11, cmd
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet manager
__name:=rgbd_manager
__log:=/home/nft/.ros/log/5efebfd8-1e6b-11e3-981d-74f06d80936b/rgbd_manager-2.log].
log file:
/home/nft/.ros/log/5efebfd8-1e6b-11e3-981d-74f06d80936b/rgbd_manager-2*.log
[rgbd_image_proc-5] process has died [pid 25379, exit code 255, cmd
/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet load
ccny_rgbd/RGBDImageProcNodelet rgbd_manager __name:=rgbd_image_proc
__log:=/home/nft/.ros/log/5efebfd8-1e6b-11e3-981d-74f06d80936b/rgbd_image_proc-5.log].
log file:
/home/nft/.ros/log/5efebfd8-1e6b-11e3-981d-74f06d80936b/rgbd_image_proc-5*.log
[ INFO] [1379293238.822060943]: Bond broken, exiting
[openni_driver-3] process has finished cleanly
log file:
/home/nft/.ros/log/5efebfd8-1e6b-11e3-981d-74f06d80936b/openni_driver-3*.log
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/79576/error-running-ccny_rgbd/) by [avalada](https://answers.ros.org/users/6686/avalada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-09-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sigmaduarte](https://answers.ros.org/users/7181/sigmaduarte/) on 2013-10-11**:
Did you find out how to fix this? I get a failure loading RGBDImageProcNodelet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well not a fix but I did a fresh install of everything, including Ubuntu and then it started working fine. What I think the problem is that there is something happening if you have both ccny_rgbd and rgbdslam installed. Maybe ccny_rgbd is using an older version of some calls or something like that.

---

Originally posted by [avalada](https://answers.ros.org/users/6686/avalada/) with karma: 31 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0